# Invalid object name 'SSISDB.catalog.customized_logging_levels'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 208)

Tags: sql-server-2016, ssis-2016

I am moving data and SSIS packages from SQL Server 2014 database server to SQL Server 2016 server.

I began with building the new server and installing SQL Server 2016 Standard edition.  Then I backed up the data on the 2014 server and restored it onto the new server 2016 server.  Including SSISDB.

One of the items that needs to be done is to go into the SQL Server Agent jobs and modify any step that is of the type SQL Server Integration package and change the server parameter in the package to the name of the new server.

However when I try to do that I get the following error message:

> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>   ADDITIONAL INFORMATION: Invalid object name 'SSISDB.catalog.customized_logging_levels'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 208)

I get the same message when I try to look at the SSISDB Integration Catalog

One article I found recommended the following steps:

- Backup SSISDB database from SSMS 2014.
- Create Integration Service catalog on SSMS 2017 and restore backup.
- Change the SSISDB database owner sa.
- Right click on SSISDB under Integration Service Catalogs.
- Select Database Upgrade-> Select Next -> Select I have taken backup of the SSISDB database. continue with the SSISDB upgrade and Select Upgrade.

The last step (SSISDB upgrade) fails with the following message:

> The SQL Server edition or version do not meet the minimum requirements to create a Master Data Services database. (Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.ISServerDBUpgrade)

I would really appreciate any advice.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You mention your 2016 is SQL Server Standard Edition - What edition was your SQL 2014?

Answer (score 0):

The first server is SQL Server 2014.

I discovered some additional information at http://radacad.com/ssis-catalog-changes-in-2016

There are a number of tables, views and stored procedures unique to SSIS 2016.  When I restored the SSIS database on the new server, these objects were overwritten.